# Check count of a column from a dataframe and and add column and count as Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am a scala beginner. I am trying to find count of null values in a column of a table and add column name and count as key value pair in Map. The below code doesn't work as expected. Please guide me how I can modify this code to make it work

```
def nullCheck(databaseName:String,tableName:String) ={
var map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]() 
validationColumn = Array(col1,col2)
for(i <- 0 to validationColumn.length) {
val nullVal = spark.sql(s"select count(*) from $databaseName.$tableName where validationColumn(i) is NULL")
if(nullval == 0)
map(validationColumn(i)) = nullVal
map
}
```

The function should return ((col1,count),(col2,count)) as Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with creating a *dynamic sql string* and then mapping it. Your approach reads same data *multiple* times

Here is the solution. I used an **"example"** DataFrame.

```
scala> val inputDf = Seq((Some("Sam"),None,200),(None,Some(31),30),(Some("John"),Some(25),25),(Some("Harry"),None,100)).toDF("name","age","not_imp_column")

scala> inputDf.show(false)
+-----+----+--------------+
|name |age |not_imp_column|
+-----+----+--------------+
|Sam  |null|200           |
|null |31  |30            |
|John |25  |25            |
|Harry|null|100           |
+-----+----+--------------+
```

and our ValidationColumns Are `name` and `age` where we shall count Nulls
we put them in a List

`scala> val validationColumns = List("name","age")`

And We Create a SQL String that will be **driving** this whole calculation

`scala> val sqlStr = "select " + validationColumns.map(x => "sum(" + x + "_count) AS " + x + "_sum" ).mkString(",") + " from (select " + validationColumns.map(x => "case when " + x + " = '$$' then 1 else 0 end AS " + x + "_count").mkString(",") + " from "  +" (select" + validationColumns.map(x => " nvl( " + x +",'$$') as " + x).mkString(",") + " from example_table where " + validationColumns.map(x => x + " is null ").mkString("or ") + " ) layer1 ) layer2 "`

It *resolves to* ==>

`"select sum(name_count) AS name_sum,sum(age_count) AS age_sum from (select case when name = '$$' then 1 else 0 end AS name_count,case when age = '$$' then 1 else 0 end AS age_count from  (select nvl( name,'$$') as name, nvl( age,'$$') as age from example_table where name is null or age is null  ) layer1 ) layer2 "`

now we create a **temporary view** of our dataframe

`inputDf.createOrReplaceTempView("example_table")`

**only thing** left to do is execute the `sql` and creating a `Map` which is done by

`validationColumns zip spark.sql(sqlStr).collect.map(_.toSeq).flatten.toList toMap`

and **result**

`Map(name -> 1, age -> 2)` // obviously you can make it type safe

Comment: Thank you ! I tried the above approach. But i am getting an error. Does Spark support aliases?

org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>( 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)

Comment: Could you paste 1) version of Spark + 2) code you tried specially the Sql building part ?

Comment: 1. version 2.3.0.cloudera4 
2. `val sqlStr = "select " + nullValidationColumn.map(x => "sum(" + x + "_null_count) AS " + x + "_null_count" ).mkString(",") + " from (select " + nullValidationColumn.map(x => "case when " + x + " = '$$' then 1 else 0 end AS " + x + "_null_count").mkString(",") + " from" +" (select" + nullValidationColumn.map(x => " nvl( " + x +",'$$') as " + x).mkString(",") + " from driver_vw where " + nullValidationColumn.map(x => x + " is null ").mkString("or ") + ") inner ) outer" `

Comment: @vvazza Can you do a spark.sql(“select * from driver_vw”).show(false) what does it show ?

Comment: `
|c1_sk|c2_sk|

|201372784                 |2013727841                 |
|201372800                 |2013728002                |
|201372792                 |2013727923                 |
|201372791                 |2013727914                 |
|199795779                 |1997957795                 |
`

Comment: I found the issue. Inner and Outer are sql keywords. I changed it to a and b and it worked fine :) Let me work on the map part now.

Comment: Also, it would be great if we change the type of Row from Array[Any] to Array[Long] by doing this `import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` and `nullValidationColumn.zip(spark.sql(sqlStr).collect.map(_.toSeq.asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Long]]).flatten.toList).toMap`